# Understanding GoogleMaps Directions API JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have the google Maps API direction json Object :

[here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal%20Studios%20Hollywood4&key=AIzaSyDeTp_6tFa2cUan9wUw3qgFi5-dm8xGRHs)

I want to show the instructions from the "STEPS" jsonArray as the user reaches a location.
Inside the "STEPS" JsonArray, there is a startLocation and endLocation object.

I know how to fetch the current location's latitude and longitude and the JSONData for a route. 
I want to **check if my current location matches with the startLocation inside the "Steps"**.

Display all the corresponding instructions (json objects such as duration, distance) from the "Steps" JSONArray.

But I don't know whether to **compare my current location with the StartLocation  or the endLocation.**

#### So what should I compare my currentLocation with?

1. StartLocation
2. endLocation

Answer (score 1):

So you have, say, 100 steps. If you're on step 0, you want to display the whole 100 steps. If you're on step 1, then you want to display steps 1 to 100, and so on.

Just check the edge cases: 
- If you're in the very beggining of the json response, then it wouldn't make sense to compare to the last point of the current step
- If you're in the last step, if your position matched the `endLocation` you should see no more instructions, so it only makes sense to display the last step when your position matches the `startLocation` of the last step.

As a corolary of the above, if your position matches the `startLocation` of step N, then display the steps from N to 100.

Which is the same that saying that, if your position matches the `endLocation` of step N, display the steps from N+1 to 100.

One last piece of advice here. When you compare the current position to the json response positions, trim or round the coordinates. Beyond the sixth digit you can safely say it's the same place. I have seen some cases in which the endLocation of a step doesn't match the startLocation of the next. Shit happens.